# how to communicate between 2 applications hosted on 2 aws elastic beanstalks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I have 2 different modules, one is **loyalty** and another one is **wallet**. (both are written in java)

loyalty app is hosted on an AWS elastic beanstalk and I have an AWS API Gateway on top of it.

now I'm about to build the wallet and it will need to use some functionalities of loyalty module. I can put it under loyalty but it wouldn't make sense since they both server different purposes.

so I thought I would put wallet on another AWS elastic beanstalk with AWS API Gateway on top but then I wonder, if wallet wants to call loyalty to use any of its functions, how should it be done? I'm not sure if it's a good idea to call the API gateway on top of loyalty to access its functions. Or is it a correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is a "correct" way depends on your architecture and design preferences. You can call one beanstalk application from another via API gateway, especially if you are calling public API methods, and one beanstalk application can call another directly (provided your subnets and security groups are set up to allow this (the default security group used set up by VPC does allow this)).

If you are intending to call private API methods in your `loyalty` app, then it would make sense to call the 'loyalty` app directly, because even assuming you have proper authentication controls on your API gateway methods it is even better for them to simply not be exposed to the public at all.

More generally, if the `loyalty` and `wallet` apps should be considered to be part of the same *service*, then I would put both under the *same* API gateway instance, and would allow `wallet` to call `loyalty` directly without going through API gateway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well I wouldn't say they are under the same service, wallet needs some of loyalty services to function but still it serves another purpose. I agree on not exposing loyalty and wallet to public, they are not supposed to be visible. I think separating them is the correct way but when you say call private API methods, it should be routed via the ebs load balancer, correct?

Comment: If neither are meant to be visible to the public, then neither should be under API Gateway, which is a public-facing service. Yes, if you call them directly the calls will hit the ELB (and the load balancer's DNS name is the one you should use when making your calls) if you are using load-balanced beanstalk apps.

Comment: apologies as it seems I've confused you. Both loyalty and wallet are supposed to be visible to public but only accessible through API Gateway so the EBS ELB it self is accessible via API GW itself but not to others even though it's still could be visible but not accessible but you're correct, I should be able to use the EBS ELB DNS name to simply access the loyalty methods.

Answer (score -2):

I am not good at AWS, but by my understanding, your question sounds like your are mixing the deployment structure and source code structure. I think you can write shared source code for both, and deploy dlls(not dll in AWS?) seperately. I think it's not good to call API gateway.

Comment: I agree on not calling the API gateway, but I don't wanna maintain a duplicate code on different environments. what's the point of having a same loyalty code in different places?

Comment: not duplicated code, a shared source code. it's normal in non-cloud project to share the same business logic layer or data access layer for multiple entrance, I guess there should be some similar way to do this.

Comment: @Simon What the OP is proposing _is_ the standard way to do this in a microservices architecture. Each "app" fulfills the same role a DLL does on a Windows machine; the difference is that the shared code is accessed by (for example) an HTTP call over a network, instead of an in-process call on the same machine.